# Sorting nonalphabet character (dash) after alphabet characters

Tags: sorting, sas

I am trying to sort a dataset as follows

```
data X;
input name$; 
    cards; 
ab 
abb
b--
ba
; run;
```

and I use

```
proc sort data=X ; by name; run;
```

the output is :

```
ab
abb
b--
ba
```

But as I see I want the output as

```
ab
abb
ba
b--
```

what is the option in proc sort that I can use (SORTSEQ option)?

Comment: I edited the title for better searchability - I feel like if someone knows to search for SORTSEQ they probably will already know the answer most of the time, and my answer includes SORTSEQ anyway.  I threw a mention of SORTSEQ in the end of the question just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way you could do this (change the sorting order so that dashes appear after alphabet characters) would be to use [`PROC TRANTAB`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/61893/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146227.htm) to define a user-defined translation table where dashes appear after those letters, and then use that in [`SORTSEQ`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146878.htm#a003194535):

For example, here I move dash to be after the letter 'z' ('{' is the character after the letter 'z' in the ASCII collation sequence):

```
proc trantab table=ascii;
  list one;
  save table=nodash;
  replace '-' '{';
    save table=nodash;
  list one;
  run;
quit;

data X;
  input name$; 
cards; 
ab 
abb
b--
ba
; 
run;
proc sort data=x sortseq='nodash';
by name;
run;
```

Comment: Good answer,  I've never had a use for `proc trantab`, but it's good to know what it does.  I had the right idea in my answer, but didn't know SAS had a built in solution!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any option that will help you here. The '-' comes before letters in ASCII and that doesn't change for other collating sequences available in the `sortseq=` option.

One way to achieve your goal is to change all non-alphabet characters to something that comes after letters in ASCII, for example a '~'.  I don't know how feasible or practical this is for your real data.